# SQL command to copy selected content from selected rows into other rows?

Tags: php, sql, mysql, phpmyadmin

Any idea how to copy: name, content from rows where language_id = 1 to rows where language_id = 2?
How should SQL command look like?

[image]

I want to achive:[image]

Comment: What is the PK for this table? My eyesight isn't good enough these days to read your image

Comment: content_id, product_id, language_id

Comment: Do you want to copy into existing rows where language_id = 2, or insert new rows where language_id = 2?

Comment: Are you saying that you need the content for a certain productid with language_id=1 replaced with that of language_id=2 ?  I don't really get the question here?

Comment: @Stofke I want to copy content(name, content,picture_path...) where language_id=1 to row where language_id=2

Comment: @Matt Gibson I want to copy selected content

Answer (score 1):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html is what you need to do

Answer (score 1):

assuming it is the productid that you want to update from lang1 to lang 2

```
update a set
a.name = b.name,
a.content = b.content
from tablea a 
join tablea b on a.productid = b.productid
where a.language_id = 2
and b.language_id = 1
```

ofcourse this will do it for every row in the table so if you want to restrict it then make sure to restrict it by the productids

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean copying *all* `language_id=1` rows to `language_id=2` ones?

My knowledge of MySQL syntax is very poor, so I dare not give you all the codez, but at least you may find the following approach useful:

1. Create a temp table with the structure like this:

   ```
   product_id int,
   name (varchar?)
   content (varchar?)
   ```

   That is, include `product_id` and all the columns you need to copy.
2. Populate the temp table with the `language_id=1` data. Probably like this:

   ```
   INSERT INTO temp_table
   SELECT product_id, name, content
   FROM orig_table
   WHERE language_id = 1
   ```
3. Update those rows in the original table where `language_id=2` with the corresponding data in the temp table. It may look like this:

   ```
   UPDATE orig_table
   SET
     name = temp_table.name,
     content = temp_table.content
   FROM temp_table
   WHERE orig_table.product_id = temp_table.product_id
     AND orig_table.language_id = 2
   ```
4. Insert the rows from the temp table into the original table, where the products don't have `language_id=2`. Something like this:

   ```
   INSERT INTO orig_table (product_id, language_id, name, content)
   SELECT product_id, 2, name, content
   FROM temp_table
   WHERE NOT EXISTS (
     SELECT 1 FROM orig_table
     WHERE product_id = temp_table.product.id
       AND language_id = 2
   )
   ```

If you didn't mean to change the already existing `language_id=2` data, then step #3 should be omitted and you might further want to modify step #2 in such a way that it selected `language_id=1` data only for the products lacking `language_id=2`.